# UncategorizedMongoDbException: unrecognized time zone identifier

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Since today we started to encounter a very strange error during running tests, and we could not find the reason why does the error persist.

```
2020-08-21 15:13:35,035 [ERROR] [] org.mongodb.driver.client: Callback onResult call produced an error
4961
com.mongodb.MongoException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 40485 (Location40485): 'unrecognized time zone identifier: "BST"' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "unrecognized time zone identifier: \"BST\"", "code": 40485, "codeName": "Location40485"}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 40485 (Location40485): 'unrecognized time zone identifier: "BST"' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "unrecognized time zone identifier: \"BST\"", "code": 40485, "codeName": "Location40485"}
```

The most important thing is `that no code changes were done to the failed test`, so our guess is that the root cause is somewhere in one of the global configurations, but we challenge to understand what is that configuration.

Any help or hint would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with `systemPropertyVariables` `user.timozone` in `maven-surefire-plugin`. Changing it to `UTC` or even deleting it fixed the issue.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <user.timezone>BTS</user.timezone>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```